# How to enable short-circuit read in HBase? (hbase-site.xml)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase

So, I have HDFS configured to do short-circuit read and I checked the short-circuit read is enabled and performed very well, when I use HDFS read APIs. (I can see the logs that the feature is successfully enabled.)

But I have no idea whether this short-circuit read is enabled or not when I run HBase upon HDFS.

So this is the property that I put in `hdfs-site.xml`, and I found the document that in
`hbase-site.xml`, I have to configure this setting too. Is this true, even though I already put this on `hdfs-site.xml` file?

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
    <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket</value>
</property>
```

That was my first question.

And is there any measure to find out HBase is performing read using short-circuit read?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any update on this? how you checked the short-circuit read is enabled in HDFS ? does it create anything in this path dfs.domain.socket.path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to set for HBase as-well. This way Hbase reads perform much better.